# Reply packets of application layer

Tags: python-3.x, networking, tcp

my task is as follows: collect some information about application-level network requests (for example, in .pcap file) and repeat these requests on another computer running python 3.6. For example, I have a pcap file with an http request to some site, I want to repeat it on another computer using some python lib, is there a way to do this? I am interested in HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, DNS, IMAP, SSH protocols. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TCPReply](https://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/installation.html#downloads) for replying a .pcap file.

Just sniff your data with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on one computer, save it to .pcap file., and you can play it later using the TCPReply tool.

Comment: the problem is that TCPReply does not take into account session specifics, so various errors may occur at the connection confirmation stage, so most of the traffic will look like a single request with a subsequent error in the response. I may be wrong, but I think it works like this. I see a possible solution to sending application le.vel requests so that the OS itself can deal with all the problems at the lower levels.